# Can someone explain the QR-Code image generation/encoding algorithm by example?

Tags: algorithm, qr-code

Right now I am working for development of qrcode algorithm for past time project.

Can someone explain the main principle of this algorithm with example?

As an example, I'd like to convert the simple statement "I love StackOverflow" into a matrix representation of a qr-code.

Comment: So you are generating the images, not recognising them?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to understand the encoding, you really need to buy the ISO specification (18004:2006). Nothing else will give you full detail enough to implement encoding.

Of course you can also look at source code implementing QR code encoding, if that's all you need. See [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing).